# Slicing certain characters for selected object in array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, slice, truncation

How to slice certain character for the selected object NOT string from array. Example,

```
date=[2017121918,2017122006,2017122012]

print date[1] : answer is 2017122006
```

My intention is to have only 122006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can you convert it to a string first, you can do this:

`str(date[1])[4:]`